# Backbone + Marionette - Memory managment best practices for Models/Collections?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, memory-management, memory-leaks, marionette

What are the best practices when destroying models/collections using `Backbone` and `Marionette`? I know that views are automagically memory managed by Marionette (if used correctly) but how about models/collections? When do you destroy them? Is it when your view gets destroyed like for instance the code (it is TypeScript instead of JavaScript) below or?

```
class SomeItemView extends Marionette.ItemView<Backbone.Model> {
    destroy() {
        super.destroy();
        delete this.model; // is this the best way to destroy a model/collection?
    }
}
```

Comment: If the model is unreferenced (0 reference count), then it is being marked for garbage collection. I'm not sure why my answer was downvoted, but when working with Marionette, the answer I provided is pretty common practice and doesn't have any memory leaks.

Comment: Ok, got it! Then it should be garbage collected together with its "parent-view" then?

Comment: If you're using a collection view or compositeview, the child views will be destroyed when the parentview gets destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably not ever need to explicitly delete your models/collections. Instead, just be sure that you are not leaving any hanging references to them.

The most common ways you are going to generate hanging references are going to be when you have models accessible via the global scope, and when you bind event listeners using `model.on` instead of `listener.listenTo(model`.

Comment: Ok, then I must be doing something wrong because it seems that none of my models are getting deallocated/destroyed. So you mean that each `listenTo` must be complemented by a `stopListening` or? 
I use the Backbone Debugger-extension for Chrome to see this (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/backbone-debugger/bhljhndlimiafopmmhjlgfpnnchjjbhd).

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to call stopListening most of the time. What I mean is that the views that have a reference to a model, should only attach event listeners through `listenTo` because those listeners will get cleaned up when the view is removed. That should mean that your models are free to be cleaned up when needed because there is no hanging listeners/references attached.

Comment: I don't know anything about that Chrome extension, so I can't really add anything about why/how it may be showing your models. It is possible that the extension is what is maintaining the references though. Another possibility is that you are using a library like `Backbone.Relational` that is storing references that prevent those models from being cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to look into Marionette Controllers and Regions.

When using

```
var region = new Marionette.Region({ el: "#container" });
```

You can use it to render a view inside:

```
var some_itemview = new Some_Itemview(); 
region.show(some_itemview);
```

If you use a Marionette Controller to instantiate models and views.

```
var some_model = new Backbone.Model(); 
//Set some properties on the model; 
var some_itemview = new Some_Itemview({ model: some_model }); 
region.show(some_itemview);
```

Then when you want to clean up the view, you can simply call:

```
region.close();
```

You can also use `region.show(another_view);` which will automatically clean up the previous view.

The view and related model should be destroyed as well as the view is the only reference to the model object.

Comment: Can you also explain why the downvote? In Marionette, closing the region should clean up the model / collection bound to the view as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation! Don't know why you were downvoted (it wasn't me).. Have a question though - I understand why you want to use a region but why should I use a Marionette Controller?

Comment: Marionette Controllers are general purpose objects that you can use for many reasons. For example, you can use it to instantiate views, manage events related to event aggregators, and the intialize / destroy functions come in handy as well.

Comment: I think you were downvoted because you were using underscore notation in javascript code.